# Assigning a value to a variable based on a boolean choice

Tags: python

```
vacationDeduction=200
vacationCheck=input('Has your employee taken 3 or more days of vacation this month? y/n: ')
    if vacationCheck=='n' is True:
        vacationDeduction=0
    elif vacationCheck=='y' is True:
        vacationDeduction=200
```

In this piece of code, I'm attempting to make the program assign the variable with a value of either 0 or 200 so that it may be subtracted from a certain calculation later in the code. Unfortnately, the program refuses to accept the `n` value, and as such always sees `vacationDeduction` as 200, ruining the calculation. How can I make it so that the program accepts `n`, and as such assigns the correct variable to `vacationDeduction`?

Comment: Please read pep8 [http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/] and some basics on `if` statement [https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if vacationCheck=='n' is True:
```

should be simply:

```
if vacationCheck=='n':
```

And the `else` clause doesn't need a condition at all:

```
else:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if vacationCheck == 'n' is True
```

**probably** evaluates to `False`<sup>1</sup>. (try `print 'n'=='n' is True`), change it to:

```
if vacationCheck == 'n':
```

Also, you don't need the `eleif`.

<sup>1</sup> This is happening because it's equivalent to:

```
if vacationCheck == ('n' is True)
```

The right side is `Flase`, and `vacationCheck` is `y` or `n`, but never `False`.

Comment: `is` checks for objects identity by id that is why 'n' is not True, unless (it's possible in python2) you didn't do `True = 'n'` before comparison.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not `input`. You should use `raw_input` to capture user input.

You can make the check more robust by checking the result this way:

```
if vacationCheck.lower() in ['y', 'yes', 't', 'true']:
   vacationDeduction = 0
elif vacationCheck.lower() in ['n', 'no', 'f', 'false']:
   vacationDeduction = 200
else:
   raise Exception("Invalid input")
```

Comment: It depends which version of Python the OP is using. Python 3 has renamed the Python 2 `raw_input` function to `input`, and the Python 2 `input` function that does an eval on the input (thankfully) doesn't exist in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Several prior answers point out that `is True` does not belong there, but not why. In many languages you would look to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for this information, but in this case you're actually (unintentionally) using [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) - the feature that permits range test of the form `bottom<=value<top`. So your conditions demanded that both `vacationcheck=='n'` and `'n' is True`, and the latter cannot be (because `is` checks for the exact same object, not equivalence, and they're only equivalent as booleans anyway). It therefore didn't matter what you entered. The only reason you got behaviour for the second case is that you had duplicated it before the tests.

The difference between raw_input and input is Python 2 behaviour, but if input ever worked for you most likely you are already using Python 3 where you don't need to worry so much.

I recommend two simple remedies: First, when unsure what effects your dynamic variable has, print it using `print repr(vacationCheck)`. This gets you the form you could enter in the interpreter, so you can verify if it actually is the value you're testing, and then verify the tests themselves:

```
>>> vacationCheck=raw_input()
n
>>> print repr(vacationCheck)
'n'
>>> vacationCheck=='n' is True
False
>>> vacationCheck=='n'
True
>>> 'n' is True
False
>>>
```

Secondly, do not check values against True or False specifically. All values have trueness, as listed under [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#booleans), so something like `is True` restricts you unnecessarily to one specific true value among an infinite set, besides risking problems like the one you've run into here.

Comment: `vacationcheck=='n' is True` can be evaluated to True if you previously redefine True as n (like this `True = 'n'`) it is allowed in python 2.x, but raise `SyntaxError` in python 3.x